# Magmi Ignore Entire Column - Not just specific rows inside a column

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, import, magmi

I know [Magmi has this page](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/MAGMI_IGNORE) about their "**MAGMI_IGNORE**" function, but it don't think it will work for my purposes.

My goal is to use specific columns with the `CONCATENATE` function (in google sheets / microsoft excel) to select `attribute options` from a `multiselect` field. The values to be `concatenated` will be separated by columns, then grouped together in the cell with the equation.

Doing this manually works without any issues when cell contents are:

`a, b, c` - values separated by comma followed by a space (with the `Value Trimmer` option enabled)

I have yet to test - and probably should have first - but I assume having the column headers be `__MAGMI_IGNORE__` will not work as desired. [Their wiki](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/MAGMI_IGNORE) only shows the function being used as a non-header row's cell value.

Has anyone else tried this and wants to answer the question with their experience so others can find this info quicker than I did?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got your idea - you have columns in your input source that are not meant to be imported directly? Can't you just remove the header for that column entirely?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. These columns are not meant to be imported or used in any attribute, but instead used with a formula without having to reference another sheet or document. I haven't tried removing the header from that column, but that could be a good solution! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the suggestion from my comment in one of my projects and I can confirm that an empty 'header column' will be ignored (no nasty side-effects like blank attributes will be created). Verified this with an Generic SQL Datasource as well.

So, to answer the question: just remove the column names of unwanted columns / columns that are not meant to be imported in your input source.

Comment: Thank you for testing this Christoph! I'll do a dry run on my site and select this as the answer once it works for me as well.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the help Christoph!